# Check if there is a node in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am checking if a node exists in Firebase. If it does I will just increment the value in that node, but if it doesn't exist I will create the node. The problem is that I'm not falling into "ELSE".

```
public void atualizarDespesaMensal(Double despesaMes, Double valorDigitado,String mesAno){

    //Recuperamos o email do usuario logado
    String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    //codificamos usando a classe Base64Custom
    String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(emailUsuario);

    movimentacaoSaldoMensalRef = firebaseRef.child("saldoMensal")
            .child(idUsuario).child(mesano);                    

    valueEventListenerAtualizarDespesaMensal = movimentacaoSaldoMensalRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          

            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                Log.i("IF", "O does not exist, we are increasing the value"); 
                
            }else{
                Log.i("ELSE", "If the node does not exist I will create"); //It's not falling here
            }   

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is the export from the firebase database.
I register a transaction in the "transaction" node, then I need to increment the value in the "balanceMonthly" node. I know how to create node and increment the value, but the problem is that I didn't fall back on "ELSE" for this.

```
{
  "movimentacao" : {
    "enVrYUBnbWFpbC5jb20=" : {
      "042021" : {
        "-MYkyj-_5Ki78nWbHsZy" : {
          "categoria" : "Mercado",
          "data" : "20/04/2021",
          "descricao" : "Compras mercado",
          "tipo" : "d",
          "valor" : 100
        },
        "-MYkzEKKttT-o50bqHl9" : {
          "categoria" : "Farmácia",
          "data" : "20/04/2021",
          "descricao" : "Compras Farmácia",
          "tipo" : "d",
          "valor" : 200
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "saldoMensal" : {
    "enVrYUBnbWFpbC5jb20=" : {
      "042021" : {
        "despesaMensal" : 300,
        "receitaMensal" : 0
      }
    }
  },
  "usuarios" : {
    "enVrYUBnbWFpbC5jb20=" : {
      "despesaTotal" : 0,
      "email" : "teste@gmail.com",
      "nome" : "Teste",
      "receitaTotal" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the database contents at `firebaseRef.child("saldoMensal").child(idUsuario).child(mesano)` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? As also Frank van Puffelen commented, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file so we can take a look at it.

Comment: I can only print from "IF".